# The "getOnItemSelectedListener" method is not working with the spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner, android-spinner

```
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_height = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Height,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter_height.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        height_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_height);

    height_spinner.getOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

**The "getOnItemSelectedListener" method is not working with the spinner.Please suggest an edit and solve my problem**
[Error is shown as above]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jym1L.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `setOnItemSelectedListener` instead of `getOnItemSelectedListener`. like the following.

```
height_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

     @Override
     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
});
```